# Inserting items in a List<>

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, parameters

I am trying to get all the words of a user built query into a List<>.

I did

```
if (columns[(a - 1)].Contains("$"))
{
    string[] splt1 = rows[b].Split('$');
    string userBuiltQuery = columns[(a - 1)].ToString();
    userBuiltQuery= userBuiltQuery.Replace("$", "");
    var pattern = new Regex(@"\w(?<!\d)[\w'-]*");
    foreach (Match m in pattern.Matches(userBuiltQuery))
    {
        words.Add(Convert.ToString(m));
    }
}
}
```

But in the foreach loop I get an error saying.

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Why so ?

Comment: Ehm... So you're asking why the piece of code with `List<string> words` fails with `NullReferenceException`, but you don't include the part where the `words` list is instantiated? :)

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek - That's probably because this error occurs when words **is not** instanciated, so he can't show code he doesn't have ;)

Comment: Can we see the declaration of the object words?

Answer (score 6):

Try initialising `words` to an instance of `List<string>` before adding elements to it.

Comment: A special kind of SO telepathy :)